# How many free space need I have if I only install basic software

Tags: disk-usage

I saw the website said that we need 25GB to install it, but if I only need an browser but not other software like office and games.

Comment: I remember installing different Linux distributions on 6-8 GB of space and having no problem... it depends on what you are trying to do and what flavor you want to install.

Comment: 6..8 Gb https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125104/how-much-storage-does-ubuntu-use/1125130

Comment: Your usage dictates the space needed (and its not just programs installed & used).  Less space means you need more regular maintenance, being more likely to come across common problems here (no space for software upgrades).  Do you plan to *nuke & start* again instead of release-upgrade? as the needed footprint is far smaller (you don't need for installed packages + compressed newer which get expanded).  There are (time) costs with too small a space you may discover.